# Audio does not play after it ends. React/

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-audio-api

I made a custom player that plays audio. After completing the file, I can't play it again. I get the error:
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().`
But I'm not sure if the error is or not.

```
const usePlayer = (src: string) => {
    const [audio] = useState(new Audio(src));
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {    
        playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
    }, [playing]);

    return {
        playing,
        setPlaying
    }
};

const Player = ({src}) => {
    const {playing, setPlaying} = usePlayer(src);

    return (
        <>
                {playing ? (
                    <button onClick={() => setPlaying(false)}>
                        pause
                    </button>
                ) : (
                    <button onClick={() => setPlaying(true)}>
                        play
                    </button>
                )}
        </>
    );
}
```

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code does not contain errors

here you can see the version I tried

I added an extra code snippet

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tu-uiqmg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: But if you use a larger file, the problem will not go away. Try this, for example https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg .

Comment: I just added audio.load() on useEffect but it not pause the audio it load again 
but file can listen again again
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-khayyam-l79jb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: After several attempts, playback still stops. https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-driscoll-fs18i